# Passing paramater to validator of composite component

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component, custom-validators

I am using Mojarra 2.3.0.
I have a composite component which contains an inputText. I want to be able to validate this inputText using a FacesValidator. Furthermore I want to pass certain parameters to the validator.

My Composite component is defined this way:

```xhtml
<composite:interface>
    ...
    <composite:editableValueHolder name="inputValidator" targets="value" />
    ...
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    ...
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="col-sm-10">
        <h:inputText  id="value"
                      disabled="#{cc.attrs.disabled}"
                      value="#{cc.attrs.value}"
                      styleClass="form-control"
                      required="#{cc.attrs.required}"
                      onchange="#{cc.attrs.onChange}"
        />
    </h:panelGroup>
    ...
</composite:implementation>
```

I use the component this way and declared a f:validator and f:attribute (which should be passed to the validator)

```xhtml
<uiComps:field labelText="add language"
           id="languages"
           autocompleteValues="#{ocrEngineViewModel.getAllSupportedLanguages()}" >
    <f:ajax event="onChange" listener="#{ocrEngineViewModel.updateSelectedLanguages}" render="newParameter:languages:value newParameter:usedLanguages" />
    <f:validator validatorId="OcrLanguageValidator" for="inputValidator" />
    <f:attribute name="allSupportedLanguages" value="#{ocrEngineViewModel.allSupportedLanguages}"/>
</uiComps:field>
<h:message for="languages" />
```

My validator looks like this:

```
@FacesValidator("OcrLanguageValidator")
public class OcrLanguageValidator implements Validator {
@Override
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    Object allSupportedLanguages = component.getAttributes().get("allSupportedLanguages");
    throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "lala", "not good"));
}
```

}

There are two problems:

1. The parameter "allSupportedLanguages" (which is a `List<String>`) is null when I try to retrieve it in the validator.
2. The ValidationException which holds a FaceMessage is not displayed in the message area for the component. I don't see any information about the message on the page.

**Update:**

Instead of the composite component I put the code directly into my page.

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="col-sm-10">
    <h:inputText  id="value" styleClass="form-control">
        <f:ajax  event="change" listener="#{ocrEngineViewModel.updateSelectedLanguages}" render="newParameter:languages:value newParameter:usedLanguages" />/>
        <f:validator validatorId="OcrLanguageValidator"/>
        <f:attribute name="allSupportedLanguages" value="#{ocrEngineViewModel.allSupportedLanguages}"/>
    </h:inputText>
</h:panelGroup>
```

This works and I see the attribute in the validator. So I guess the problem lies in the usage of the composite component.

**Update2:**

I was able to solve the validation error message problem. I placed the `<h:message for="value"/>` inside the composite component.

Comment: I guess you mean Mojarra 2.3.0, which it is not still in stable state: https://javaserverfaces.github.io/ Also I think your problem is well stated, but it would be better to post an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it becomes testable without the need of writing any extra code (it might be useful to include a sample project as well).

Comment: @xtremebiker: it is https://javaee.github.io/javaserverfaces-spec/ oracle just does a bad job maintainimg those pages. Thank god its all moving to Eclipse

Comment: The attribute tag is a child of the composite not of the validator. Sure that is your intention? (I never used these constructs so just guessing)

Comment: @XtremeBiker you are right. I meant 2.3.0. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Kukeltje Actually I don't exactly know if this is my intention;) I'm new to jsf and try to understand it. But I noticed that when I am shifting the f:attribute into the f:validator it seems that the validator is not executed at all.

Comment: Does it work if you don't use a custom component but directly use the code?

Comment: @Kukeltje Yes it works if I put the code directly into the page. I've updated the question with that.